# CountIf Application or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a code that keeps on returning a run-time error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error. I've tried stepping through the individual parts of the worksheetfunction.countif function, and they all work fine separately.

However, when I put them together, they fail.

The code is:

```
s = 2

While Cells(s - 1, 1) <> vbNullString

    Rows(s & ":" & s + 3).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range(Cells(s, 1), Cells(s + 3, 1)).Select
    Selection.Rows.Group
    Cells(s, 1) = "A"
    Cells(s + 1, 1) = "B"
    Cells(s + 2, 1) = "C"
    Cells(s + 3, 1) = "D"

    r = 3
    q = vbNullString
    p = vbNullString
    n = s

    While n < s + 5
        While r <= v
            M = 1
            If Cells(n, 1) = "A" Then
                q = 5
                p = 12
            ElseIf Cells(n, 1) = "B" Then
                q = 18
                p = 25
            ElseIf Cells(n, 1) = "C" Then
                q = 31
                p = 38
            ElseIf Cells(n, 1) = "D" Then
                q = 44
                p = 51
            End If

            While M <= u
                l = vbNullString
                l = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("IT Teams").Range(Cells(q, M), Cells(p, M)), Worksheets("Players IT").Cells(s + 4, 1))
                If Not IsError(l) Then
                    Cells(n, r) = l
                Else
                    Cells(n, r) = vbNullString
                End If
                M = M + 5
                r = r + 1
            Wend

        Wend
        n = n + 1
        r = 3
    Wend

    s = s + 5
Wend
```

All variables have been declared as Variants.

Edit: for clarity. Error occurs at:

`l = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("IT Teams").Range(Cells(q, M), Cells(p, M)), Worksheets("Players IT").Cells(s + 4, 1))`

Comment: Please specify the line where the error occurs.

Comment: Are there any cases for which `Cells(n,1)` isn't A, B, C or D?

Comment: Are you working with two separate sheets?

Comment: No, A, B, C, D will always be there. There are cases where the value in s+4 won't be in the area being searched.

Comment: @Davesexcel searching the "IT Teams" sheet from a different sheet that is activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you declare the ranges. You should always include the sheet, otherwise you get this error, if you use more than one sheet (or if you use one, but it is not the active one).

Like this:

```
With ActiveSheet
    While Cells(s - 1, 1) <> vbNullString

        .Rows(s & ":" & s + 3).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range(.Cells(s, 1), .Cells(s + 3, 1)).Select
        Selection.Rows.Group
        .Cells(s, 1) = "A"
        .Cells(s + 1, 1) = "B"
        .Cells(s + 2, 1) = "C"
        .Cells(s + 3, 1) = "D"
    Wend
End With
```

Pay attention to the dots.

In general, declare the sheets and then use them:

```
'Option Explicit - start using option explicit
Sub test()

    Dim wksA        As Worksheet
    Dim wksIT       As Worksheet

    Set wksA = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set wksIT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IT Teams")

    s = 2
    While Cells(s - 1, 1) <> vbNullString

        wksA.Rows(s & ":" & s + 3).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        wksA.Range(wksA.Cells(s, 1), wksA.Cells(s + 3, 1)).Select
        Selection.Rows.Group
        wksA.Cells(s, 1) = "A"
        wksA.Cells(s + 1, 1) = "B"
        wksA.Cells(s + 2, 1) = "C"
        wksA.Cells(s + 3, 1) = "D"
    Wend

    With wksIT

        While M <= u
            l = vbNullString
            l = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(q, M), _
                                       .Cells(p, M)), .Cells(s + 4, 1))
                If Not IsError(l) Then

                .Cells(n, r) = l
            Else
                .Cells(n, r) = vbNullString
            End If
            M = M + 5
            r = r + 1
        Wend
    End With

End Sub
```

Concerning your case, I am about 80% sure, that you get the error somewhere here:

```
    l = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(q, M), Cells(p, M)), Cells(s + 4, 1))
```

In general, never assume which worksheet your code is operating on and explicitly define it in your code.

Concerning the place where you get the error, it should be simply like this:

```
    Set wksA = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set wksIT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IT Teams")
    Set wksPl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SomePlayers")

    l = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wksIT.Range(wksIT.Cells(q, M), wksIT.Cells(p, M)), _
    wksPl.Cells(s + 4, 1))
```

Comment: I think that also the `Cells` inside the errant line must be qualified. see *"searching the "IT Teams" sheet from a different sheet that is activated"*

Comment: @A.S.H - that's fun, I  guessed correctly where the error appears :)

Comment: @Vityata You guessed correctly at where the error is. I've added in additional code to tell it to search a particular location, but still getting the same error. Will try and rewrite using your examples.

Comment: @Clauric - make sure to rewrite your code again, using the `wksA` and `wksIT` for every declaration of `Cells` or `Range`. Also `wksPlayer`, as far as I see that you have a third sheet.

Comment: "Players IT" is the second sheet.

Comment: @Clauric - the order does not matter, as far as you write the names when you set them.

Comment: Worked perfectly with the suggested changes. Thank you

Comment: @Clauric - great. In general, when you have time, read the VBA Best practices - https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices#t=20170601124043380758 They can save you hours of headaches.